# How to sync audio with lottie / rive animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, lottie, rive

I need to make an animation with voice acting for 10-15 minutes. As far as I know, lottie and rive do not support audio in their animations. Is it a good solution to run the audio track in parallel with the animation? There are concerns that there may be an out of sync. Has anyone solved a similar problem?

Comment: I think controlling animation state and audio won't be that much problem, I made a some-sort of space-shooter with rive.

Comment: Have you been able to figure it out? I'm researching the same issue.